# What does 'Lee' in an title of a person mean?

Tags: meaning

Recently I found a very cute tale by John Ruskin(1819-1900) called Dame Wiggins of Lee, and Her Seven Wonderful Cats. But then, I got curious about what does 'Lee' mean here? I know the Dame is a title for women with special honor. 
Does 'Lee' represent the name of the place?

If you want to see the book, you can find it here.
https://archive.org/details/damewigginsoflee00peariala

Comment: Yes, the straightforward interpretation of what you post is that *Lee* is the name of a place.  It is common for aristocrats to add toponyms, often but not always the names of places their ancestors wrested from the grasp of the peasantry, to their styles and titles.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark This lady is not an aristocrat, however. The modern meaning of _Dame_ is the feminine equivalent to a knighthood, but in Ruskin's time it just meant an old lady. Lee is presumably where she lived. There is a district of that name in London.

Comment: She's a *Dame* ain't she ?  To us peasants they're all aristos.

Comment: More seriously: to my reading of the situation the old lady has acquired a title (be it ever so 'umble and lacking letters patent) and the toponym to go with it.  And yes, *Lee* is presumably where she lived, but it may be where she came from.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark In a British sense a knight, or dame - or any person of wealth or influence might at one time have been known as *gentry*. Jane Austen's heroic families are undoubtedly *gentry* - nowadays "upper middle class" or "socio-economic class B". One might need to be an hereditary peer to be considered *aristocracy*. The words are not used nowadays, other than in an ironic or humorous sense. The distinctions will be somewhat different in other European countries, but the OED defines *aristocrat* as strictly *"one of a ruling oligarchy*", which a dame or a knight would not be.

Comment: From Wikipedia "Dame" - _The title of dame as the official equivalent of knight was introduced in 1917 with the introduction of the Order of the British Empire,_ This is **not**  what Ruskin was referring to.

Comment: @KateBunting, probably they made the title officially equivalent to *knight* because the word *dame*  was already being used in a similar way in colloquial speech. At the very least it was already a highly respectful word for a woman.

Comment: I think the use of *dame* to mean a woman of relatively high social standing goes back further than 1917 though. From a quick Google it looks to me as though it my have acquired this meaning during Ruskin's lifetime - so I suspect it just indicates that the Wiggins in question is an adult female, but I don't think we can be absolutely certain. Either way, I think Lee is a place - it's just that if *dame* is an aristocratic title it isn't necessarily the place she comes from, any more than the Duke of Cambridge comes from Cambridge.

Comment: @JD2000 [In Johnson's Dictionary](https://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/page-view/?i=532) (1755) it's defined as "the title of honour to women". He says that it was historically used for a "lady", but by his time was more often used for a farmer's wife, while still being used in poetry to indicate a "woman of rank".

Comment: @ThePhoton thanks for the link. So in fact it had this meaning throughout his lifetime - perhaps the question is when it lost the plain meaning of *adult female*, but I suspect that both meanings were current and we would have to read the story to figure out which one Ruskin had in mind. My feeling is that it just means *Mrs Wiggins of Lee*, but it's no more than a feeling.

Comment: @KateBunting, also, the [1911 Encyclopedia Brittanica](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/1911_Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica/Dame) indicates that *dame* was used at that time as "the legal designation of the wife or widow of a baronet or knight and prefixed to the Christian name and surname." So the term wasn't completely without official standing as an indicator of rank before 1917.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm reposting part of my comments so that the poor chap(-ess) asking
>   the question gets a clear answer, free of the extended commentary
>   about the proper interpretation of the word *Dame* which is all rather
>   beside the point ...

Yes, the straightforward interpretation of what you post is that *Lee* is the name of a place.  It may well be the place the dame comes from or came from, it may be the name of the place where she resides.  It may even be an entirely different place.  But you are correct to think that it *is* the name of *a* place.